# react native android app upgrade crashes but fresh install is OK

Tags: android, react-native, crash, upgrade

Recently have been thru React Native hell and back, having had to upgrade some packages to support Android 11 permissions issues, we basically ended up having to upgrade a whole heap of RN packages and other stuff to newer versions.

Just about every package needed some love along the way.

After much massaging we have managed to get both debug and release APK'a built and they run fine on both Android simulator and physical devices, and Google have also accepted the release APK into internal testing track. So far so good...

The issue arises when we install the current Play Store version of our app and then add myself to the internal testers track and update the app. The new version of the app always crashes after the app is upgraded.

If I simply install the newer version without having the previous version installed then the app runs 100% fine.

I'm just wondering if anyone else has ever encountered such an issue and if they had any pointers for us in where to start hunting this down.

Obviously would prefer to be able to upgrade vs fresh install for all our install base but perhaps there has been too many breaking changes from older version APK to this new one?

Any guidance is greatly appreciated

UPDATE - Found some kind of codepush crash in the adb logcat output.

Currently suspecting that the new app doesn't like the old apps codepush binary for the old version. Its at least a thread to pull on.

With fresh install there is no old codepush binaries to get in the way of app startup

Comment: Hi Mark! Did you find a solution for this yet? We are currently running into the exact same problem - we upgraded RN from `0.63.x` to `0.66.2` and also a lot of packages and now are having exactly the same problem. Any help is appreciated!